# is it possible to force a WCF service into a faulted state for testing?

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0

I am trying to test a service that sometimes faults due to the known issues with .NET 4 and MSMQ. see this [post](http://sergiochong.blogspot.com/2011/02/troubleshooting-asynchronous.html)

Of course now that I have implemented the code to handle the fault and restart the service I can't reproduce it (it happens really rarely). Is there somewhere I can force it to go into the faulted state ([CommunicationState.Faulted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.communicationstate%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)). I need to test my code which is essentially copied form the blog post with a little added logging and the addition of a key value pair to hold some information about the service.

```
void FaultedServiceHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Logger.Error(new Exception(string.Format("ServiceHost received a service fault event from {0}", sender)));

            var faultedServices = _services.Where(t => t.Value.Host != null && t.Value.Host.State == CommunicationState.Faulted).ToList();

            foreach (var serviceKvp in faultedServices)
            {
                 serviceKvp.Value.Host.Closed -= new EventHandler(ServiceClosedEventHandler);
                    serviceKvp.Value.Host.Abort();
                    serviceKvp.Value.Host = null;

                    // Now open up a new instance of this service.
                    ServiceStartup(serviceKvp.Value.Definition);
                    LogEvent(String.Format("Host {0} was found in a faulted state.", serviceKvp.Key));
                    Logger.Error(new Exception("FaultedServiceHandler: Aborting " + serviceKvp.Key + " Host and Restarting."));
            }
        }
```

Seriously - this is like Murphy's law. The thing won't break now that I need to test the fix.

Comment: If you don't need to reproduce an exact kind of error, you could modify your code to throw an exception - as long as it is not handled the service will fault.

Comment: Yeah - thanks. I finally got it to break so I could test but I will keep that in mind

Comment: Can you please share how you got it to a faulted state?

Comment: Sorry - It actually just broke on it's own. I wasn't able to force it.

Comment: almost 3 year old Post, but here is the Solution: just throw an Exception -> throw new Exception();

Comment: throw exception didn't work for me. The service simple keeps running. I was able to reproduce the state by stopping MSMQ service. Not the way to automate the test, but it works. If there is a way to make it enter fault state from code, someone please explain